# Not work callback for textillate

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, effect, jquery-textillate

```
 var $tlt = $('#q').textillate({ 
    autoStart: false,       
    in: { effect: 'fadeOutUp',
          callback: function () {        
               alert("Hi !");    
         }
    }
    });

   $tlt.textillate('start')
```

This did not work, plugin: http://jschr.github.io/textillate/

[callback on guthub](https://github.com/agam360/textillate/commit/782674dd07319dfed3bfbeb5c149c67364f2a383#jquery-textillate-js-P13)

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks/Events are now implemented in textillate: https://github.com/jschr/textillate